# expand axis (add padding) for log-scaled plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a simple line:

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)

dt1 <- data.table(time=c(0,31,150,230,300), value=c(2,0.2,0,0,10))
dt1[, result:=ifelse(value>0,'POSITIVE','NEGATIVE')]

p1 <-
ggplot(dt1, aes(x=time, y=value, fill=result, group=1)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size=3,shape=21) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('white','black'))
```

[image: linear scale]

Now, I want to show it in a log scale, with `0.01` used as a lower limit:

```
p1 + scale_y_log10(limits=c(0.01,NA))
```

[image: Log scale]

I can't find how to add some sort of padding at the bottom, to avoid "cropping" of the lower points. I tried playing with `expand` and `oob` but could not find a working solution so far.

Comment: You can turn off cropping aka clipping like so: `ggplot() + ... +  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')`. Expanding a log scale won't make it reach down to zero.

Comment: @I_O highlights the fundamental problem that you're trying to display a y value of zero on a log scale, but if you want to force it, you can set `y=pmax(0.01, value)` (then you might want to edit the y-axis label too).

Comment: Thank you @Miff I know it's technically incorrect maybe, but for my visualization purposes it's acceptable. Nice workaround with `pmax()`, but I like @I_O solution even better as it does not require changes in the original plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pseudolog transformation function from the scales package:

```
ggplot(dt1, aes(x=time, y=value, fill=result, group=1)) + 
    geom_line() +
    geom_point(size=3,shape=21) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c('white','black'))+
    scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans())
```

[image]